# Oracle READ WRITE mode in postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, amazon-web-services, database-migration, amazon-aurora

I am migrating Oracle database to Postgres Aurora. There is one Oracle PL/SQL block which checks if the database is in read write open mode. Below is the query like:

```
Select open_mode into v_open_mode from v$database;
if v_open_mode = 'READ WRITE' then
-- perform some steps.
```

I want to know if we have any equivalent query in Postgres. Or even if I can know the postgres node is WRITE mode.

I am also open to get anything which is native to Aurora which show if the node is reader or writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the Oracle thing does, but I assume the closest thing would be to check if Postgres is in recovery mode using [`pg_is_in_recovery()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-CONTROL)

So something like:

```
 if not pg_is_in_recovery() then 
    -- do some steps
 end if;
```

That is from "stock" Postgres, I don't know if Amazon Aurora does anything different or provides other functions.